# Locally hosted GAE + WordPress - image upload http-error

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I've setup my WordPress site on Google App Engine. I have my installation mirrored locally. When trying to upload multiple images via Media > Add New I'm getting an `Http-error`. Only the first image is uploading. All other images say 100% progress but don't crunch and complete the upload.

I'm working locally from: `http://localhost:9080/wp-admin/upload.php`.

All plugins are de-activated except for Google App Engine for WordPress 1.6

The error doesn't occur on my live version, only on my local version.

> At Settings > App Engine I have a custom bucket name specified.
>
> At Settings > App Engine Use secure URLs for serving media files is off.

The images I'm trying to upload have hyphenated names and are `PNG` or `JPG`.

Memory is 256: `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');`

Debug is true: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` `Http-error` is the only error.

Details of the error from Console are as follows:

```
POST http://localhost:9080/_ah/upload/agxkZXZ-cHVyby05NzJyIgsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxiAgICAgIDACww 404 (Not Found)

load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,plupload-handlers&ver=4.2.2:23 POST http://localhost:9080/_ah/upload/agxkZXZ-cHVyby05NzJyIgsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxiAgICAgIDACww 404 (Not Found)
```

Any ideas for troubleshooting would be most welcome.

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the clean-up @NETCreator Hosting - WebDesign. Appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. You can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help some help related to Stack Overflow editor.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the link. As you can see I'm new here. I'll be sure to check that out.

Comment: You are welcome. You should check out the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Possible answer:

**METHOD 1**

Try to replace lines 195 and 196, from GAE plugin directory `/modules/uploads.php` with:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE[$auth_cookie_name])) { $_COOKIE[$auth_cookie_name] = $auth_cookie; }
if (!isset($_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE])) { $_COOKIE[LOGGED_IN_COOKIE]  = $logged_in_cookie; }
```

**METHOD 2**

This error is happening from `Wordpress 4.0`. If you downgrade your version to 3.9 or older (not recommended by security reasons) the error shouldn't appear.

**METHOD 3**

Make a back-up before taking any action.

Try re-uploading all files & folders - **EXCEPT** the `wp-content` folder - from a fresh download of WordPress on local.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: The change has unfortunately not fixed my local error. The good news is that this error isn't occurring in my live version. I'll keep digging and/or consider the downgrade or live with the issue. Thanks again for your efforts on this. Appreciate it :)

Comment: You are welcome. I edited the answer and you can try `method 3`. Hope the problem will be solved.

Comment: Phew, still no love with solution 3 or even solution 2, rolling back to 3.9. So I guess something else is up. I'll go back to the logs with my Sys. Admin at the weekend and try figure out what's up. I'll post here if we manage to resolve. Thanks so much for your efforts!